# androidTest-results folder not created when executing connectedAndroidTest on jenkins machine

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I am trying to get the xml file from the `androidTest-results` folder on the Jenkins machine.

When I run the `connectedAndroidTest` on my mac, everything is fine but when I do it on the Jenkins machine it runs but doesn't create the reports.
It also happens when I run the `testUnitTest` command and the Jacoco task for creating coverage reports.

I have tried specifying the `resultsDir` but it doesn't help me with Junit tests and with Jacoco coverage results.

What am I missing?

Comment: You could try passing in `--info` or `--debug` to Gradlew when you run on Jenkins to get some more insight into what's happening. Judging by your question, the Jenkins host is not a Mac - is it running Linux or Windows?

Comment: Actually it is on a mac. I think it might be missing some configuration somewhere because i never launched android studio on the jenkins machine.

Comment: Have you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same problem